# Vshosts folder created after each F5 run

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vshost.exe

Every time I run the app it creates a vshosts folder in the bin\debug folder in the following format:

```
 [appname].vshost_[hh-mm-ss]
```

for example:

```
 mCommAttempt.vshost_16-33-57`
```

The folder is always empty and ofcourse the regular vshost exe file is in bin\debug as well. I'm using VS 2008 with C#.

What is this, why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

its name suggests that the folder is used for the vshost.exe. Probably used for storing temporary files at each run for the vshost.exe

vshost.exe is the VS Debug Host Process. The Visual Studio uses it to:

1. improve debug performance
2. partial trust debugging
3. expression evaluation at design time.

Take a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331(VS.80).aspx) for detailed information.

Comment: I know what vshost does, I just don't understand why I'm getting folders after each run. If it's temp why isn't it deleted after the run?